# Cursor keeps busy for 15 seconds when runnig a command from a launcher icon

Tags: command-line, scripts, launcher, cursor

Following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Using_a_text_editor) easy guide I was able to create a .desktop file. my goal was to pin this desktop file to the launcher and add two commands to it as quick list items here is what I did :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Launcher2Dock
Comment=Turnes you laucher intoto dock
Exec=gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Left
Icon=/home/mushir/Desktop/icon.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
Actions=Move bottom;Move left
[Desktop Action Move bottom]
Name=Move bottom
Exec=gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
OnlyShowIn=Unity; 
[Desktop Action Move left]
Name=Move left
Exec=gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Left
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

everything worked just fine but I found that the mouse cursor turns into the wheel shape for about 15 seconds after runing the command from the .desktop file quick list pinned to the laucnher

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the link, the launcher is waiting for a window, which will not appear. In the answer there is a workaround for that. Please comment here if you (don' t) manage. Alternatively, you could use a shortcut key to toggle, similar to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/781358/how-to-put-unity-launcher-on-in-different-positions-on-different-monitors/781373#781373 , but that would require a small change of the question.

Comment: Hi Misho21, please also see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/744658/launcher-icon-to-start-a-script-keeps-blinking-and-is-unresponsive-for-seven-s/744665#744665 to complete the picture.